# How to generate 2 jars from one gradle project with different dependencies using sring boot plugin 2.0.x

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, gradle-plugin, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to migrate my project to latest versions Spring and Spring Boot. Everything was going smothly till I encounter this problem.

One of our project generates two versions of final Jar, one plain runnable with minimum dependencies, and another one with all extra modules.

While I was using Spring Boot version 1.5.x, then solution was simple, we used 'customConfiguration`

when i was using old plugin, my config file looks more or less like that

```
bootRepackage{ 
    customConfiguration = "addons"
}


dependencies {
    compile "my.org:core-lib:1.0.0"
    addons  "my.org:extra-lib:1.0.0"
}
```

now `bootRepackage` is replaced by `bootJar` which does not hold property `customConfiguration`. Is this is possible to do in latest version of plugin, if yest, then could someone point me in right direction please.

Comment: This won't build two separate jars as `bootRepackage` will overwrite the jar that's produced by the `jar` task. If your description of the behaviour is accurate, there must be more to your build's configuration than you've shown here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

bootJar is a sub class of Jar class, so you can use Jar task's configurations here.

Example:

```
configurations {
    //second jar's configuration
    addons
}

dependencies {
    ....
    // sample dependency
    addons group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.11.1'
}

task customJar(type: org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.bundling.BootJar){
    baseName = 'custom-spring-boot'
    version =  '0.1.0'
    mainClassName = 'hello.Application'
    from {
        // this is your second jar's configuration
        configurations.addons.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }

    with bootJar
}
// add a dependency to create both jars with gradle bootJar Command
bootJar.dependsOn customJar
```

(There can be easier ways do this that I don't know about)

Comment: I hope there is another way because i don't really like this solution. It was so nice and clean in old version. i upvote it and if i cannot find anything better then i will accept it. Thanks

Comment: @user902383 why you don't like this solution? There's no other.

Comment: @Opal maybe i express myself wrong, i don't have a problem with solution but with change which was done to the plugin.way how it was done in old version feels more cleaner. But as i said, if this is only one way i'm happy to accept it